# One Modal Bootstrap two action

Tags: jquery, session, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal that shows once your data in session and once empty fields in order to create a new user from the admin (I have two buttons "New" and "User In Session" that are pointing to the same modal). I used the session to populate the fields "User in session" with jQuery and I've deleted them to facilitate the insertion of the new user. Once erased, however, I have no more the button "User in session."

How do I order to repopulate the fields with the session once deleted?

```
<div id="modalInsertOrUpdate" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header centerMyText">

                <h4 class="modal-title">Gestione Dati</h4>
            </div>

            <form id="formInserOrUpdate" class="form-horizontal" action="updateUtente.action">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <s:textfield readonly="true" type="text" name="id"
                                         value="%{#session.utenteLoggato.id}"
                                         class="form-control"
                                         id="id"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <a href="#" id="infoId" data-toggle="popover" rel="popover" title="ID"
                               data-content="ID generato automaticamente"><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <s:textfield type="text" name="nome" class="form-control"
                                         value="%{#session.utenteLoggato.nome}"
                                         id="nome"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cognome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cognome</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <s:textfield type="text" name="cognome" class="form-control"
                                         value="%{#session.utenteLoggato.cognome}"
                                         id="cognome"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mail</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <s:textfield type="email" cssErrorClass="errorLabel" name="mail" class="form-control"
                                         value="%{#session.utenteLoggato.mail}"
                                         id="mail"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <s:textfield type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control"
                                         value="%{#session.utenteLoggato.telefono}"
                                         id="telefono"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <s:if test='#session.utenteLoggato.tipoUtente.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin")'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipoUtente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Permessi</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select name="tipoUtente" id="tipoUtente" disabled>
                                    <option value="user" selected>User</option>
                                    <option value="admin"
                                            <s:if test='#session.utenteLoggato.tipoUtente.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin")'>selected</s:if> >
                                        Admin
                                    </option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </s:if>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <s:textfield type="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                                         id="password"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <a href="#" id="infoButton" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover" title="Password"
                               data-content="La password deve essere di 8 caratteri."><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="passwordAgain" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ripeti Password</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <s:textfield type="password" name="passwordAgain" class="form-control"
                                         id="passwordAgain"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                </button>
                                <s:submit type="button" id="modificaButton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Modifica</s:submit>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



<ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMyPassword">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Password</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id="myUtente" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalInsertOrUpdate">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Personale</span></a></li>

        <s:if test='#session.utenteLoggato.tipoUtente.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")'>
            <li><a href="#" id="addUtente" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalInsertOrUpdate">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> *New</span></a></li>
        </s:if>

        <li><a href="index.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"> Logout</span></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
<s:include value="modalInsertOrUpdate.jsp"></s:include>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: @MassimoMannini you simply added the modal code... There's only a submit button and a close button... Where are the buttons you're talking about and how do you erase the fields?

Comment: I have 2 href pointing the same modal, with Jquery when I press New cleanse fields!

Comment: If u can help I'm also using struts2

Comment: I saw... I'm creating an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case it's easier to store the session data into hidden input fields and use JQuery in order to retrieve them when clicking one button or the other one, here you have a working fiddle. For time purposes I've used a simple form but you can always change the code in order to fit for your modal. Hope this could help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#new').click(function() {
    $('.form-input').each(function(index, element){
      $(this).val('');
    });
  });
  
  $('#session').click(function() {
    $('.form-input').each(function(index, element){
      $(this).val($('#hidden-' + $(this).attr('id')).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="new">New</button>
<button type="button" id="session">Session</button>

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-username" value="abcd">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-email" value="abcd@abcd.it">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-name" value="abcd">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-surname" value="abcd">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="id" value="1">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="username" value="abcd">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="email" value="abcd@abcd.it">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="name" value="abcd">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="surname" value="abcd">
  <input type="password" id="password">
  <input type="password" id="password-confirm">
</form>
```

Of course since you're using Struts2 the hidden inputs shouldn't refer to any variable in your action with getter/setter or they will be called.

Another solution may-be using data attribute like this:

```
<!-- In your form put the data attributes -->
<form id="myForm" data-id="%{#session.utenteLoggato.id}" data-username="%{#session.utenteLoggato.username}"> <!-- and so on -->

<!-- Modify the script in order to get data attribute instead of val -->
$('#session').click(function() {
  $('.form-input').each(function(index, element){
    $(this).val($('#myForm').data($(this).attr('id')));
  });
});
```

This second solution i think can be more "elegant"

Comment: Good, I have found another solution. I created a variable of type object and I set the values.